# Theme.Holo on Android 4.4

Tags: android, themes

I'm trying to put `Theme.Holo` on my android app
I already put `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo` on my manifest and my `min sdk` is set to 11 but I'm still getting an error
Am I suppose to edit something in `styles.xml`?
I'm running on android 4.4 (API 19)
Please help.

Comment: add this in your application tag in manifest file.              tools:ignore="NewApi"

Comment: Please explain what "an error" is.

Comment: So do I just copy-paste the logcat so you guys can see? Sorry, noob here:D @CommonsWare